# How to pass multiple files as parameter to a function in shell script

Tags: shell

how to copy files one by one to destination path when multiple files are sent as parameter to function in form of Regex.

```
copyFiles()  
{  
  for file in $@  
  do  
    echo "File:" $files  
    cp -f $file $TARGET_DIR   #how to copy files one by one to destination path
  done  
}  
TARGET_DIR=destinationPath/Dir  
copyFiles sourcePathFiles/filename.*         #How to handle this in copyFiles()
```

Comment: I don't see any regexp in your code. Maybe you can clarify what you mean here.

Comment: Why not pass `copyFiles sourcePathFiles/filename.` and then in `copyFiles()` do `for file in "$1"*`? (note the `*` must be OUTSIDE the quotation of `"$1"` or you will suppress the pathname expansion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly correct, but:

(1) You are using `$@`. This would break if the argument being passed contains spaces. You should use `"$@"`.

(2) In your `echo` command, you refer to a variable `files`, which is not being set. In your `cp`, you correctly refer to `file`.

Actually, your function can be simplified a bit:

```
copyFiles()  
{
   cp -vf "$@" $TARGET_DIR
}
```

The use of `-v` obviates the need for the `echo`.